# Set EXECUTE sp_executesql result into a variable in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have to set a dynamic sql query result to a variable. My sql query is :

```
DECLARE @ResultString NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)  

SET @Qry='SELECT Test FROM MTest22Dec WHERE ID = 1'      
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Qry, N'@Result NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @Result=@ResultString OUTPUT
PRINT @ResultString
```

But `@ResultString` is printing empty string although there is record in database table.

What is wrong in this query?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the output variable somewhere, eg.

```
SET @Qry='SELECT @Result = Test FROM MTest22Dec WHERE ID = 1'
```

Comment: And since `@Qry` is an `NVARCHAR` variable, you should **really** use the `N` prefix to make this clear: `SET @Qry = N'SELECT @Result = Test FROM MTest22Dec WHERE ID = 1'`

Answer (score 6):

You need to assign the result of select to `variable` inside `Dynamic statement`.

Change you query like this.

```
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Qry='SELECT @Result = Test FROM MTest22Dec WHERE ID = 1'

EXECUTE Sp_executesql @Qry, N'@Result NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @Result OUTPUT

PRINT @Result
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @ResultString NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)  

SET @Qry='SELECT @ResultString = Test FROM MTest22Dec WHERE ID = 1'      
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Qry, N'@ResultString NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @ResultString OUTPUT
PRINT @ResultString
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this :

```
Declare @Query NVARCHAR(100)
Declare @ResultString varchar(50)

set @Query =N'select @ResultString=Test from dbo.MTest22Dec where id = @id'

exec sp_executesql @Query, N'@id int,@ResultString varchar(20) output',
@id = 1,@ResultString=@ResultString output

print @ResultString
```

Comment: I would suggest you add some commentary around the code, and format the code as code.  ( there is button in the editor that marks your text as code in the answer )

Comment: You this Code Which will help you